# flex4 maven compile,TypeError: Error #1007: Instantiation attempted on a non-constructor,AdvancedDataGrid

Tags: maven, apache-flex, flex4, advanceddatagrid

There is multiple module project, A is application, B,C,D is module. Compile successful,but when I load module B ,pop up error:

```
TypeError: Error #1007: Instantiation attempted on a non-constructor.
    at mx.controls.dataGridClasses::DataGridHeader/updateDisplayList()
    at mx.core::UIComponent/validateDisplayList()
    at mx.managers::LayoutManager/validateClient()
    at mx.core::UIComponent/validateNow()
    at mx.controls.dataGridClasses::DataGridBase/updateDisplayList()
    at mx.controls::DataGrid/updateDisplayList()
    at mx.controls.listClasses::ListBase/validateDisplayList()
    at mx.managers::LayoutManager/validateDisplayList()
    at mx.managers::LayoutManager/doPhasedInstantiation()
        at mx.managers::LayoutManager/doPhasedInstantiationCallback()
```

after research get some document：
http://blog.flexicious.com/post/Errror-Instantiation-attempted-on-a-non-constructor.aspx
It seems like I just need to compile the special style into my application.I did( A had referenced the style file by )
compile successful,run,still exist the error.
I think maybe the application can not compile css to swf  by 
so I add some compile css script to the maven pom.xml

```
<buildCssFiles>
  <path>styles/temp.css</path>
</buildCssFiles>
```

still pop up error.

Does anyone encounter the same problem!

Comment: How to compile style css file to the swf by maven.

Answer (score 0):

general solution, 
step 1:add the special style script to the style file.

```
mx|AdvancedDataGrid{
    columnDropIndicatorSkin: ClassReference("mx.skins.halo.DataGridColumnDropIndicator");
    columnResizeSkin: ClassReference("mx.skins.halo.DataGridColumnResizeSkin");
    headerColors: #FFFFFF, #E6E6E6;
    headerDragProxyStyleName: "headerDragProxyStyle";
    headerBackgroundSkin: ClassReference("mx.skins.halo.DataGridHeaderBackgroundSkin");
    headerSeparatorSkin: ClassReference("mx.skins.halo.DataGridHeaderSeparator");
    headerHorizontalSeparatorSkin: ClassReference("mx.skins.halo.AdvancedDataGridHeaderHorizontalSeparator");
    headerStyleName: "advancedDataGridStyles";
    sortArrowSkin: ClassReference("mx.skins.halo.DataGridSortArrow");
    stretchCursor: Embed(source="Assets.swf",symbol="cursorStretch");
}

mx|AdvancedDataGridSortItemRenderer{
    paddingTop: 0;
    paddingBottom: 0;
    paddingLeft: 0;
    paddingRight: 0;
    horizontalGap: 0;
    color: #0B333C;
    icon: ClassReference("mx.skins.halo.DataGridSortArrow");
}

mx|PrintAdvancedDataGrid{
    alternatingItemColors: #FFFFFF, #FFFFFF;
    borderColor: 0;
    columnResizeSkin: ClassReference("mx.skins.halo.DataGridColumnResizeSkin");
    headerColors: #FFFFFF, #FFFFFF;
    headerSeparatorSkin: ClassReference("mx.skins.halo.DataGridHeaderSeparator");
    headerStyleName: "advancedDataGridStyles";
    horizontalGridLineColor: 0;
    horizontalGridLines: true;
    sortArrowSkin: ClassReference("mx.skins.halo.DataGridSortArrow");
    stretchCursor: Embed(source="Assets.swf",symbol="cursorStretch");
    verticalGridLineColor: #000000;
}

mx|PrintOLAPDataGrid{
    alternatingItemColors: #FFFFFF, #FFFFFF;
    borderColor: 0;
    columnResizeSkin: ClassReference("mx.skins.halo.DataGridColumnResizeSkin");
    headerColors: #FFFFFF, #FFFFFF;
    headerSeparatorSkin: ClassReference("mx.skins.halo.DataGridHeaderSeparator");
    headerStyleName: "advancedDataGridStyles";
    horizontalGridLineColor: 0;
    horizontalGridLines: true;
    stretchCursor: Embed(source="Assets.swf",symbol="cursorStretch");
    verticalGridLineColor: #000000;
}
```

step 2: add script to the pom.xml

```
<compilerWarnings>
    <show-unused-type-selector-warnings>false</show-unused-type-selector-warnings>
</compilerWarnings>
```